# adding Tab bar to masterview (Tableview) in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uitableview, master-detail

So my problem is that I would like to add a Tab bar to my existing Master View.
Also My search bar won't stay on top.

[image]

[image]

Here are some images of the storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your problem.

Keep in mind that Tab Bar Controllers and Navigation View are also View Controllers (VC) to serve other VCs. Saying so, you have to organize your story board controllers in order to have the Tab Bar Controler as the root VC and a Navigation VC as parent of your master view in order to keep the master/detail navigation.